# improve the performance of this slow query

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I want to tune this query for a better performance.

Query:

```
SELECT `DeviceRawUsage`.`duration`, `DeviceRawUsage`.`current` 
FROM `epowerg`.`device_raw_usages` AS `DeviceRawUsage`   
WHERE `DeviceRawUsage`.`device_id` = 1 AND 
`DeviceRawUsage`.`outlet_id` = 1 AND 
`DeviceRawUsage`.`duration` >= '2015-06-01 00:00:00' AND 
`DeviceRawUsage`.`duration` <= '2015-06-30 23:59:59';
```

Comment: Might be worth adding a `LIMIT` to the number of results you want back - if practical for this scenario. I.e. if you want 10 results: add `LIMIT 10` to the end of the query.

Comment: @user3065931 i can't limit it . I want the query to be tuned as much as it get . is any other way that i can make this query efficient ?

Comment: Do you have indices defined for your columns `device_id`,`outlet_id`, etc. ?

Comment: Please show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE device_raw_usages`

Comment: Provide the table definition, MySQL settings and most important - output of `EXPLAIN`. @user3065931 - LIMIT has no impact here, it never makes selects faster - please do read about how LIMIT works internally (MySQL gathers all the records then discards everything starting at OFFSET for LIMIT amount of rows).

Comment: @user3065931 :   Replied !

Comment: @N.B. - `LIMIT` _sometimes_ makes a select faster.  It depends on the index, the `ORDER BY`, etc.  In this case, he has to do a table scan to find the desired records.  If 10 of them happen to be near the start of the table, `LIMIT 10` will speed up the query.  With the index I propose, the "range" scan of the index could be cut short.

Comment: @RickJames - it never makes it faster, nor does it depend on any of the things you mentioned. However, if you have a solid proof it *does* then by all means - do post it. If `LIMIT` operates by discarding everything minus `LIMIT` rows then it can't make the query faster. It can just reduce the amount of data transferred back. It depends on no indexes, only index comparisons can reduce the data set scanned.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `device_raw_usages` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`device_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`outlet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`duration` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`current` float(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`voltage` float(11,4) NOT NULL,
`kw_used` float NOT NULL,
`outlet_total_kwh` float(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`outlet_kwh_demand_15` float(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`outlet_kw_demand_peak` float(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`submeter_real_kw` float(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`submeter_total_kwh` float(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`submeter_kwh_demand_15` float(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`submeter_kw_demand_peak` float(11,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`peak_voltage` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`peak_current` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`demand` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`inst_demand` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`hist_peek_demand` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`power_factor` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`crest_factor` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`frequency` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`app_power` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`tot_app_energy` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`tot_har_dist_vol` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`tot_har_dist_curr` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`har_x_dist_v` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`har_y_dist_v` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`har_z_dist_v` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`har_x_dist_c` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`har_y_dist_c` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`har_z_dist_c` float(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`interval` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1136511 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

To optimize, add a *composite* index:

```
INDEX(device_id, outlet_id, duration)
```

Unrelated comments:

- `FLOAT(m,n)` is almost always the wrong thing to do.  Consider either `DECIMAL(m,n)` or plain `FLOAT`.
- Are those columns really optimal?  Use `NOT NULL` where appropriate.

**Edit**

Assuming you already have the table built, you can add the index by doing:

```
ALTER TABLE device_raw_usages ADD INDEX(device_id, outlet_id, duration);
```

This particular index is beneficial to the *one* `SELECT` you provided.  It may or may not help with other `SELECTs`.  [Here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) is a short cookbook on how to write the 'best' `INDEX` for a given `SELECT`.

Comment: can you use the index on query and post it . i m new to it . i would like to know how you do it .. and i will imply on my other queries .